# Using ScrollView Programmatically in Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, uiscrollview, autolayout

I have searched other questions and seem to still have some trouble creating my scrollView programmatically with autolayout in swift 3. I am able to get my scrollview to show up as shown in the picture below, but when I scroll to the bottom my other label does not show up and the 'scroll top' label does not disappear.

[image: ScrollView]

Hoping someone can help review my code below!

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

let labelOne: UILabel = {
    let label = UILabel()
    label.text = "Scroll Top"
    label.backgroundColor = .red
    label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return label
}()

let labelTwo: UILabel = {
    let label = UILabel()
    label.text = "Scroll Bottom"
    label.backgroundColor = .green
    label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return label
}()


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let screensize: CGRect = UIScreen.main.bounds
    let screenWidth = screensize.width
    let screenHeight = screensize.height
    var scrollView: UIScrollView!
    scrollView = UIScrollView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 120, width: screenWidth, height: screenHeight))
    scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: screenWidth, height: 2000)
    scrollView.addSubview(labelOne)
    scrollView.addSubview(labelTwo)


    view.addSubview(labelOne)
    view.addSubview(labelTwo)
    view.addSubview(scrollView)

    // Visual Format Constraints
    view.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "H:|[v0]|", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(), metrics: nil, views: ["v0": labelOne]))
    view.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "V:|-100-[v0]", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(), metrics: nil, views: ["v0": labelOne]))

    // Using iOS 9 Constraints in order to place the label past the iPhone 7 view
    view.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: labelTwo, attribute: .top, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: labelOne, attribute: .bottom, multiplier: 1, constant: screenHeight + 200))
    view.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: labelTwo, attribute: .right, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: labelOne, attribute: .right, multiplier: 1, constant: 0))
    view.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: labelTwo, attribute: .left, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: labelOne, attribute: .left, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)     

    }

}
```

Comment: Why are you adding your labels to both the scrollview and the UIView?

Comment: ^ This. You added the subviews to the view, not the scroll view. You're also going to need to set up some constraints between `labelTwo` and `scrollView` so that `scrollView` can correctly calculate the content size.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

It is easy to use constraints to define the scroll content size - so you don't have to do any manual calculations.

Just remember:

1. The *content elements* of your scroll view must have left / top / width / height values. In the case of objects such as labels, they have intrinsic sizes, so you only have to define the left & top.
2. The *content elements* of your scroll view ***also*** define the bounds of the scrollable area - the `contentSize` - but they do so with the bottom & right constraints.
3. Combining those two concepts, you see that you need a "continuous chain" with at least one element defining the top / left / bottom / right extents.

Here is a simple example, that will run directly in a Playground page:

```
import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport

class TestViewController : UIViewController {

    let labelOne: UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel()
        label.text = "Scroll Top"
        label.backgroundColor = .red
        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return label
    }()
    
    let labelTwo: UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel()
        label.text = "Scroll Bottom"
        label.backgroundColor = .green
        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return label
    }()

    let scrollView: UIScrollView = {
        let v = UIScrollView()
        v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        v.backgroundColor = .cyan
        return v
    }()
    
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        // add the scroll view to self.view
        self.view.addSubview(scrollView)
        
        // constrain the scroll view to 8-pts on each side
        scrollView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leftAnchor, constant: 8.0).isActive = true
        scrollView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: 8.0).isActive = true
        scrollView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.rightAnchor, constant: -8.0).isActive = true
        scrollView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor, constant: -8.0).isActive = true
        
        // add labelOne to the scroll view
        scrollView.addSubview(labelOne)
        
        // constrain labelOne to left & top with 16-pts padding
        // this also defines the left & top of the scroll content
        labelOne.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.leadingAnchor, constant: 16.0).isActive = true
        labelOne.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.topAnchor, constant: 16.0).isActive = true
        
        // add labelTwo to the scroll view
        scrollView.addSubview(labelTwo)
        
        // constrain labelTwo at 400-pts from the left
        labelTwo.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.leadingAnchor, constant: 400.0).isActive = true

        // constrain labelTwo at 1000-pts from the top
        labelTwo.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.topAnchor, constant: 1000).isActive = true
        
        // constrain labelTwo to right & bottom with 16-pts padding
        labelTwo.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.rightAnchor, constant: -16.0).isActive = true
        labelTwo.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.bottomAnchor, constant: -16.0).isActive = true
        
    }
    
}


let vc = TestViewController()
vc.view.backgroundColor = .yellow
PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = vc
```

---

**Edit** - since this answer still gets occasional attention, I've updated the code to use more modern syntax, to respect the safe-area, and to use the scroll view's `.contentLayoutGuide`:

```
class TestViewController : UIViewController {
    
    let labelOne: UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel()
        label.text = "Scroll Top"
        label.backgroundColor = .yellow
        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return label
    }()
    
    let labelTwo: UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel()
        label.text = "Scroll Bottom"
        label.backgroundColor = .green
        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return label
    }()
    
    let scrollView: UIScrollView = {
        let v = UIScrollView()
        v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        v.backgroundColor = .cyan
        return v
    }()
    
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        // add the scroll view to self.view
        self.view.addSubview(scrollView)

        // add labelOne to the scroll view
        scrollView.addSubview(labelOne)
        
        // add labelTwo to the scroll view
        scrollView.addSubview(labelTwo)
        
        // always a good idea to respect safe area
        let safeG = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide
        
        // we want to constrain subviews to the scroll view's Content Layout Guide
        let contentG = scrollView.contentLayoutGuide
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            
            // constrain the scroll view to safe area with 8-pts on each side
            scrollView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: safeG.topAnchor, constant: 8.0),
            scrollView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: safeG.leadingAnchor, constant: 8.0),
            scrollView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: safeG.trailingAnchor, constant: -8.0),
            scrollView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: safeG.bottomAnchor, constant: -8.0),
            
            // constrain labelOne to leading & top of Content Layout Guide with 16-pts padding
            // this also defines the left & top of the scroll content
            labelOne.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentG.topAnchor, constant: 16.0),
            labelOne.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentG.leadingAnchor, constant: 16.0),

            // constrain labelTwo leading at 400-pts from labelOne trailing
            labelTwo.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: labelOne.trailingAnchor, constant: 400.0),
            
            // constrain labelTwo top at 1000-pts from the labelOne bottom
            labelTwo.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: labelOne.bottomAnchor, constant: 1000),
            
            // constrain labelTwo to trailing & bottom of Content Layout Guide with 16-pts padding
            // this also defines the right & bottom of the scroll content
            labelTwo.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentG.trailingAnchor, constant: -16.0),
            labelTwo.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentG.bottomAnchor, constant: -16.0),
            
        ])
        
    }
    
}
```

Comment: You just blew my mind with this liveView in a storyboard thing. Is it possible to scroll on it?

Comment: I am trying to achieve the same thing but stuck with your second point. Can you please elaborate?

Comment: I think I have figured it out. Your answer is in fact the only relevant answer I was able to find anywhere over the internet. There a number of YouTube videos as well but the way you have helped is superb! Thank you @DonMag

Comment: Instead of using constraint equal to view , i suggest using self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.

Answer (score 12):

Two things.

**1. Add the labels to scroll view, not your view**

You want your label to scroll with scroll view, then you should not add it on your view. When running your code, you can scroll but the fixed label there is pinned to your view, not on your scroll view

**2. Make sure you added your constraints correctly**

Try it on your storyboard about what combination of constraint is enough for a view. At least 4 constraints are needed for a label.

**Bottom line**

Here is a modified version of your code. For constraint I added padding left, padding top, width and height and it works. My code is

```
let labelOne: UILabel = {
    let label = UILabel()
    label.text = "Scroll Top"
    label.backgroundColor = .red
    label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return label
}()

let labelTwo: UILabel = {
    let label = UILabel()
    label.text = "Scroll Bottom"
    label.backgroundColor = .green
    label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return label
}()


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let screensize: CGRect = UIScreen.main.bounds
    let screenWidth = screensize.width
    let screenHeight = screensize.height
    var scrollView: UIScrollView!
    scrollView = UIScrollView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 120, width: screenWidth, height: screenHeight))

    scrollView.addSubview(labelTwo)

    NSLayoutConstraint(item: labelTwo, attribute: .leading, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: scrollView, attribute: .leadingMargin, multiplier: 1, constant: 10).isActive = true
    NSLayoutConstraint(item: labelTwo, attribute: .width, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .notAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: 200).isActive = true
    NSLayoutConstraint(item: labelTwo, attribute: .top, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: scrollView, attribute: .topMargin, multiplier: 1, constant: 10).isActive = true
    NSLayoutConstraint(item: labelTwo, attribute: .height, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .notAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: 30).isActive = true

    scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: screenWidth, height: 2000)
    view.addSubview(scrollView)

}
```

And the scroll view looks like this

[image]

Comment: "1. Add the labels to scroll view, not your view", this is NOT needed

Comment: @J.Doe Please read through the problem that OP was having. He's complaining about label1 not scrolling with scroll view and that the second label is not showing up. This is caused directly by adding two labels to the view of the base view controller, instead of the scroll view to make them scrollable. I'm not sure what do you mean by this is not needed.

Answer (score 2):

For me this work like charm

```
class WithDrawConfirmationViewController: UIViewController, WithDrawConfirmationViewProtocol {

    var presenter: WithDrawConfirmationPresenterProtocol?
    private let viewbackgroundColor = UIColor(hexString: "#F5F5F8")
    // MARK:- View properties
    lazy var scrollView: UIScrollView = {
        let scrollView = UIScrollView()
        //view.backgroundColor = .red
        scrollView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return scrollView
    }()
    
    lazy var contentView: UIView = {
        let view = UIView()
        //view.backgroundColor = .green
        view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return view
    }()
    
    lazy var headerView: UIView = {
        let view = UIView()
        view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return view
    }()
    
    private lazy var titleLabel:UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel()
        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        label.textColor = UIColor.themeBlack
        label.text = "Withdraw Confirmation"//"Loading.."
        label.textAlignment = .center
        label.font = UIFont(name: "AvenirNext-DemiBold", size: 20)
        label.numberOfLines = 0
        label.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping
        return label
    }()
    
    
    private lazy var descriptionLabel:UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel()
        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        label.textColor = UIColor.themeGray
        label.text = "Please confirm your fixed deposit details before withdrawing your deposit"// "Loading.."
        label.textAlignment = .center
        label.font = UIFont(name: "AvenirNext-Medium", size: 14)
        label.numberOfLines = 0
        label.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping
        label.setContentHuggingPriority(1000, for: .vertical)
        return label
    }()
    
    private lazy var instructionLabel: UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel()
        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        label.textColor = UIColor.themeGray
        label.text = "Complete fixed deposit will be withdrawn and the money will be debited to your account within 1-2 working days."//"Loading.."
        label.textAlignment = .left
        label.font = UIFont(name: "AvenirNext-Medium", size: 14)
        label.numberOfLines = 0
        label.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping
        return label
    }()
    
    private lazy var warningLabel: UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel()
        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        label.textColor = UIColor.themeBlue
        label.text = "Axis bank will levy a penalty of 1% - 2% for premature withdrawal"//"Loading.."
        label.textAlignment = .left
        label.font = UIFont(name: "AvenirNext-DemiBold", size: 13)
        label.numberOfLines = 0
        label.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping
        return label
    }()
    
    private lazy var warningView: UIView = {
        let view = UIView()
        view.cornerradius = 5
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor(hexFromString: "#E8F4FD")
        view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return view
    }()
    private lazy var fdInformationDetailView: FDPurchaseDetailView = {
        let view = FDPurchaseDetailView(isPoweredByViewVisible: false)
        //view.backgroundColor = .red
        view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return view
    }()
    
    private lazy var footerCTAView: FooterButtonViewView = {
        let view = FooterButtonViewView()
        view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return view
    }()
    
    // MARK:- Life cycle
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        contentView.backgroundColor = viewbackgroundColor
        scrollView.backgroundColor = viewbackgroundColor
        setUpUI()
        presenter?.viewDidLoadTriggered()
    }

    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    }
    
    private func setUpUI() {
        view.addSubview(scrollView)
        scrollView.addSubview(contentView)
        view.backgroundColor = viewbackgroundColor
        addFooter()
        setUpHeaderView()
        setUpFDDetailView()
        setUpInformationAndWarningView()
        //scrollView.backgroundColor = .lightGray
        scrollView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        scrollView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
        scrollView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor).isActive = true
        scrollView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: footerCTAView.topAnchor).isActive = true
        scrollView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 100, right: 0)
        
        contentView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        contentView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
        contentView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.topAnchor).isActive = true
        contentView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        contentView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor).isActive = true
        //contentView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: footerCTAView.topAnchor).isActive = true
    }
    
    private func setUpHeaderView() {
        contentView.addSubview(headerView)
        headerView.addSubviews([titleLabel, descriptionLabel])
        
        headerView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leadingAnchor, constant: 20).isActive = true
        headerView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.trailingAnchor, constant: -20).isActive = true
        headerView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.topAnchor, constant: 4).isActive = true
       
        titleLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: headerView.leadingAnchor, constant: 8).isActive = true
        titleLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: headerView.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
        titleLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: headerView.topAnchor, constant: 8).isActive = true
        
        descriptionLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: titleLabel.bottomAnchor, constant:  20).isActive = true
        descriptionLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: headerView.leadingAnchor, constant: 8).isActive = true
        descriptionLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: headerView.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
        descriptionLabel.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: headerView.bottomAnchor, constant: -20).isActive = true
    }
    
    
    private func setUpFDDetailView() {
        contentView.addSubview(fdInformationDetailView)
        fdInformationDetailView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: headerView.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        fdInformationDetailView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leadingAnchor, constant: 20).isActive = true
        fdInformationDetailView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.trailingAnchor, constant: -20).isActive = true
       
    }
    
    private func setUpInformationAndWarningView() {
        contentView.addSubview(instructionLabel)
        
        instructionLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: fdInformationDetailView.bottomAnchor, constant: 20).isActive = true
        instructionLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leadingAnchor, constant: 20).isActive = true
        instructionLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.trailingAnchor, constant: -20).isActive = true
        
        warningView.addSubview(warningLabel)
        warningLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: warningView.topAnchor, constant: 8).isActive = true
        warningLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: warningView.leadingAnchor, constant: 20).isActive = true
        warningLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: warningView.trailingAnchor, constant: -20).isActive = true
        warningLabel.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: warningView.bottomAnchor, constant: -8).isActive = true
        
        contentView.addSubview(warningView)
        
        warningView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: instructionLabel.bottomAnchor, constant: 8).isActive = true
        warningView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leadingAnchor, constant: 20).isActive = true
        warningView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.trailingAnchor, constant: -20).isActive = true
       //warningView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
        warningView.bottomAnchor.constraint(greaterThanOrEqualTo: contentView.bottomAnchor, constant: -20).isActive = true
        
    }
    
    private func addFooter() {
        view.addSubview(footerCTAView)
        footerCTAView.delegate = self
        footerCTAView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        footerCTAView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
        footerCTAView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Set scrollview images to the wallpaper:

```
@IBOutlet var scroll_view_img: UIScrollView!

var itemPhotoList = NSMutableArray()

var button = NSMutableArray()    

@IBOutlet var imageview_big: UIImageView!

override func viewDidLoad() {

    super.viewDidLoad()
    itemPhotoList = ["grief-and-loss copy.jpg","aaa.jpg","image_4.jpeg"]        

    // button = ["btn1","btn2"]

    let width:CGFloat = 100
    let height:CGFloat = 100
    var xposition:CGFloat = 10
    var scroll_contont:CGFloat = 0

    for i in 0 ..< itemPhotoList.count
    {
        var button_img = UIButton()
        button_img = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: xposition, y: 50, width: width, height: height))
        let img = UIImage(named:itemPhotoList[i] as! String)
        button_img.setImage(img, for: .normal)
        scroll_view_img.addSubview(button_img)
        button_img.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonAction), for: .touchUpInside)
        button_img.tag = i
        view.addSubview(scroll_view_img)
        xposition += width+10
        scroll_contont += width
        scroll_view_img.contentSize = CGSize(width: scroll_contont, height: height)
    }
}

func buttonAction(sender: UIButton!)
{
    switch sender.tag {
    case 0:
        imageview_big.image = UIImage(named: "grief-and-loss copy.jpg")
    case 1:
        imageview_big.image = UIImage(named: "aaa.jpg")
    case 2:
        imageview_big.image = UIImage(named: "image_4.jpeg")
    default:
        break
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Copy and paste this controller in your project

```
class BaseScrollViewController: UIViewController {

lazy var contentViewSize = CGSize(width: self.view.frame.width, height: self.view.frame.height + 100)
lazy var scrollView: UIScrollView = {
    let view = UIScrollView(frame: .zero)
    view.backgroundColor = .white
    view.frame = self.view.bounds
    view.contentSize = contentViewSize
    view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return view
}()
lazy var containerView: UIView = {
    let v = UIView()
    v.backgroundColor = .white
    v.frame.size = contentViewSize
    return v
}()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    view.backgroundColor = .white
    view.addSubview(scrollView)
    scrollView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor).isActive = true
    scrollView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
    scrollView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
    scrollView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true

    scrollView.addSubview(containerView)
    setupContainer(containerView)
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
}

public func setupContainer(_ container: UIView) {
    
}
```

}

> Usage for above code:

```
class ClientViewController: BaseScrollViewController {
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // do your stuff here
}

override func setupContainer(_ container: UIView) {
    // add views here
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Here is my approach with `UIStackView` as a container for `UIScrollView` (in my opinion it's more flexible than provided answers) :

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    private let scrollView : UIScrollView = {
        let view = UIScrollView()
        view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false
        view.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = false
        view.backgroundColor = .black
        return view
    }()

    private lazy var scrollViewContainer: UIStackView = {
        let view = UIStackView()
        view.axis = .vertical
        view.spacing = 0
        view.distribution = .fill
        view.alignment = .fill
        view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return view
    }()
    
    private lazy var redView: UIView = {
        let view = UIView()
        view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.backgroundColor = .red
        return view
    }()
    
    private lazy var whiteView: UIView = {
        let view = UIView()
        view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.backgroundColor = .white
        return view
    }()

    private lazy var blueView: UIView = {
        let view = UIView()
        view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.backgroundColor = .blue
        return view
    }()

    private func setupSubViews() {
        scrollViewContainer.addArrangedSubview(whiteView)
        scrollViewContainer.addArrangedSubview(blueView)
        scrollViewContainer.addArrangedSubview(redView)
        
        let itemHeight: CGFloat = 100
        
        let constraints = [
            whiteView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: itemHeight),
            blueView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: itemHeight),
            redView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: itemHeight)
        ]
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate(constraints)
    }

    private func setupScrollView()
    {
        view.addSubview(scrollView)
        
        scrollView.addSubview(scrollViewContainer)

        let safeArea = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide
        
        let constraints = [
            scrollView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: safeArea.leadingAnchor),
            scrollView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: safeArea.trailingAnchor),
            scrollView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: safeArea.topAnchor),
            scrollView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: safeArea.bottomAnchor),

            scrollViewContainer.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.leadingAnchor),
            scrollViewContainer.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.trailingAnchor),
            scrollViewContainer.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.topAnchor),
            scrollViewContainer.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.bottomAnchor),
            scrollViewContainer.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.widthAnchor)
        ]
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate(constraints)
    }
    

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        setupScrollView()
        setupSubViews()
    }
}
```

Answer (score -9):

These answers do not work with large titles in the navigation bar. Make sure you have the code below in your viewDidLoad() method of your view controller:

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = false
```