# Swift how can I get UIScrollView dynamic height

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, nslayoutconstraint

I googled but have not found working solution, I have `UIScrollView` adding inside `UITextField` and `UIButtons` with `NSLayoutConstraint`, I don't use storyboard and setting everything programmatically

my issue is: can't calculate dynamic height of `UIScrollView.contentSize` because I am using AutoLayout
also tryed `UIScrollView.layoutIfNeeded()` but no luck

can any one guide or advice me how to to get it work?

Comment: https://www.natashatherobot.com/ios-autolayout-scrollview/

Comment: Here's a complete example - you can even run it in a Playground page: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44933358/6257435

Comment: thanks @DonMag your answer inspired me to right direction just added last object bottom constraint and it worked

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@DonMag's comment was right solution to my problem
[stackoverflow.com/a/44933358/6257435](http://stackoverflow.com/a/44933358/6257435)

if you have in `UIScrollView` objects with AutoLayout don't forget add `.bottomAnchor` to last item

Answer (score 0):

Sum of scrollview subview’s height and constraint constants is the final height. Even after constraints layed out, it’s always summ. So just calculate it, and you height. But why do you need calculating scrollview’s content height? If it’s adjusting wrong, set your subviews height constraints, top and bottom contraints to scrollview, and content size will be calculated automatically