# Set UIScrollView content dynamically with Autolayout

Tags: ios

I am using Autolayout with UIScrollView in XCode 9. I wish to have a horizontal paging scrollview with 2-3 pages. I have set a ContentView as the single childview and put constraints on all edges so it aligns with the scroll view. The PageViews are then children of the ContentView.

```
  UIView
    UIScrollView
       ContentView
          PageView1
          ....
```

This works great and autolayout works for the scrollview. However I wish to change the content view size, sometimes 2 pages otherwise 3. I have an initial constraint on the ContentView width of twice the outer UIView width with priority set to 250.

If at runtime I change the ContentView frame so the width is increased, this does not get set and the ContentView remains at its original size, I imagine iOS is changing the frame back.

Anyone know how to do this?

Comment: There are many, many examples of this, if you do a little searching. Here is just one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44931898/using-scrollview-programmatically-in-swift-3/44933358#44933358

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First i would recommend using `UICollectionView` / `UIStackView` for this issue , second changing frame width won't help , every item appended  should have leading constraint to the previous trailing , top&bottom&trailing to contentView , then scrollview will autoresize to show that added item