# UIScrollview does not show all subviews and is not scrollable

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview

I have some problems with scrollview. I added a ScrollView to my ViewController with simple UIViews. But the ScrollView does not scroll and it does not show all my subviews.

I followed this example [IOS swift scrollview programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52897537/ios-swift-scrollview-programmatically) but somehow my code does not work. Here is my example

```
import UIKit
class StatisticsViewController: UIViewController{ 

    let scrollView: UIScrollView = {
        let view = UIScrollView()
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray.adjust(by: 28)
        view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return view
    }()

    let topstatsView: UIView = {
        let view = UIView()
        view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.backgroundColor = .red
        return view
    }()

    let resultsView: UIView = {
         let view = UIView()
         view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
         view.backgroundColor = .systemPink
         return view
     }()

    let blue: UIView = {
        let view = UIView()
        view.backgroundColor = .blue 
        view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return view
    }()

    let yellow: UIView = {
        let view = UIView()
        view.backgroundColor = .yellow
        view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return view
    }()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    self.view.addSubview(scrollView)

    // constraints of scroll view
    scrollView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leftAnchor).isActive = true
    scrollView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor).isActive = true
    scrollView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
    scrollView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.rightAnchor).isActive = true


    scrollView.addSubview(topstatsView)
    scrollView.addSubview(resultsView)
    scrollView.addSubview(blue)
    scrollView.addSubview(yellow)

    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        topstatsView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.topAnchor, constant: 40),
        topstatsView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.leftAnchor, constant: 30),
        topstatsView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 250),
        topstatsView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.rightAnchor)
    ])

    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        resultsView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.topAnchor, constant: 330),
        resultsView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.leadingAnchor, constant: 30),
        resultsView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 400),
        resultsView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 450)
    ])

    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        blue.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.topAnchor, constant: 330),
        blue.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: resultsView.rightAnchor, constant: 20),
        blue.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 400),
        blue.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.rightAnchor, constant: -30)
    ])


     NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
         yellow.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.topAnchor, constant: 800),
         yellow.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.trailingAnchor, constant: 20),
         yellow.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 400),
         yellow.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.trailingAnchor, constant: -30)
     ]) 
}
```

Here is a screenshot of my example. 
[image]

As you can see the red view (topstatsView) does not confirm the right anchor and you cannot see the yellow and blue ones. And it is not scrollable. I am not able to see my mistakes. Thanks in advance!

Comment: A tip: don't mix `.leftAnchor / .leadingAnchor` ... use `.leadingAnchor`. Same with `.rightAnchor / .trailingAnchor` ... use `.trailingAnchor`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you define wrong constraint.

1) Always add constraints related to each views top, bottom, leading and trailing, instead of define top constraint of all views to a scrollview.

2) Its not a good practise to add both leading and trailing anchor when you already define a width anchor.

3) Add bottom constraint related to a scrollview bottom to make it scrollable.

4) Add leading and trailing constraint related to outerView instead of adding it related to a scrollview.

Here is the updated code:-

class StatisticsViewController: UIViewController{

```
let scrollView: UIScrollView = {
    let view = UIScrollView()
    view.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray
    view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return view
}()

let topstatsView: UIView = {
    let view = UIView()
    view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    view.backgroundColor = .red
    return view
}()

let resultsView: UIView = {
    let view = UIView()
    view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    view.backgroundColor = .systemPink
    return view
}()

let blue: UIView = {
    let view = UIView()
    view.backgroundColor = .blue
    view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return view
}()

let yellow: UIView = {
    let view = UIView()
    view.backgroundColor = .yellow
    view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return view
}()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.view.addSubview(scrollView)

    // constraints of scroll view
    scrollView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leftAnchor).isActive = true
    scrollView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor).isActive = true
    scrollView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
    scrollView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.rightAnchor).isActive = true


    scrollView.addSubview(topstatsView)
    scrollView.addSubview(resultsView)
    scrollView.addSubview(blue)
    scrollView.addSubview(yellow)

    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        topstatsView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.topAnchor, constant: 40),
        topstatsView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.leftAnchor, constant: 30),
        topstatsView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 250),
        topstatsView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.rightAnchor, constant: -30)
    ])

    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        resultsView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topstatsView.bottomAnchor, constant: 30),
        resultsView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.leadingAnchor, constant: 30),
        resultsView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 400),
        resultsView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.rightAnchor, constant: -30)
    ])

    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        blue.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: resultsView.bottomAnchor, constant: 30),
        blue.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.leftAnchor, constant: 20),
        blue.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 400),
        blue.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.rightAnchor, constant: -30)
    ])


    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        yellow.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: blue.bottomAnchor, constant: 30),
        yellow.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.leadingAnchor, constant: 20),
        yellow.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 400),
        yellow.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.trailingAnchor, constant: -30),
        yellow.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.scrollView.bottomAnchor, constant: -20)
    ])
}
```

}

Comment: Then its better to add those two views in stackView and then add stackView to a scrollview. First try it on your own.

Comment: OK, I will try. Thank You !