# Can I make a scrollview on xcode 12 without specifying content height

Tags: uiscrollview, swift5, xcode12

Okay, I'm a relatively new Swift developer and I just started learning scrollviews. All the tutorials I've seen always specify a particular height for the content view so as to activate the scrollview.
Is there a way to make a scrollview without specifying the height. Checking it on bigger screens the content view is actually cut off the scrollview and that's not good UI design.

Comment: *Specifying content height* is very out-of-date. You should be using auto-layout constraints. Do some searching, and go through examples and tutorials that are not 5 years old. Here is just one example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63890754/6257435

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Step-by-Step...

1. Add a view controller to your Storyboard
2. Add a scroll view to the view controller
3. Constrain it with 20-pts Top / Bottom / Leading / Trailing
4. Add two labels to the scroll view - position one near the top-left and the other near the bottom-right
5. Constrain the First label Top: 8 and Leading: 8 *to the scroll view's **Content Layout Guide***
6. Constrain the Second label Bottom: 8 and Trailing: 8 *to the scroll view's **Content Layout Guide***
7. Constrain the Second label Leading to the First label Trailing
8. Constrain the Second label Top to the First label Bottom
9. Change **that** constraint constant to a large number - such as 1200

If you've done it right, it should look something like this:

[image]

You cannot see the Bottom-Right-Label because it is 1200-pts below the top label (so, it's off the bottom of the view).

Run the app, and you will have a vertically scrolling view.

Here's the source to that Storyboard so you can inspect it directly:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<document type="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder3.CocoaTouch.Storyboard.XIB" version="3.0" toolsVersion="17156" targetRuntime="iOS.CocoaTouch" propertyAccessControl="none" useAutolayout="YES" useTraitCollections="YES" useSafeAreas="YES" colorMatched="YES" initialViewController="uUy-L1-OnG">
    <device id="retina3_5" orientation="portrait" appearance="light"/>
    <dependencies>
        <deployment identifier="iOS"/>
        <plugIn identifier="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder.IBCocoaTouchPlugin" version="17125"/>
        <capability name="Safe area layout guides" minToolsVersion="9.0"/>
        <capability name="System colors in document resources" minToolsVersion="11.0"/>
        <capability name="documents saved in the Xcode 8 format" minToolsVersion="8.0"/>
    </dependencies>
    <scenes>
        <!--View Controller-->
        <scene sceneID="Rrc-66-RYL">
            <objects>
                <viewController id="uUy-L1-OnG" sceneMemberID="viewController">
                    <view key="view" contentMode="scaleToFill" id="39G-hU-x3e">
                        <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="320" height="480"/>
                        <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" widthSizable="YES" heightSizable="YES"/>
                        <subviews>
                            <scrollView clipsSubviews="YES" multipleTouchEnabled="YES" contentMode="scaleToFill" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="2QQ-od-V3W">
                                <rect key="frame" x="20" y="20" width="280" height="440"/>
                                <subviews>
                                    <label opaque="NO" userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="left" horizontalHuggingPriority="251" verticalHuggingPriority="251" text="Bottom-Right Label" textAlignment="natural" lineBreakMode="tailTruncation" baselineAdjustment="alignBaselines" adjustsFontSizeToFit="NO" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="6dS-VR-QcN">
                                        <rect key="frame" x="131" y="1229" width="149" height="21"/>
                                        <color key="backgroundColor" red="0.99953407049999998" green="0.98835557699999999" blue="0.47265523669999998" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="sRGB"/>
                                        <fontDescription key="fontDescription" type="system" pointSize="17"/>
                                        <nil key="textColor"/>
                                        <nil key="highlightedColor"/>
                                    </label>
                                    <label opaque="NO" userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="left" horizontalHuggingPriority="251" verticalHuggingPriority="251" text="Top-Left Label" textAlignment="natural" lineBreakMode="tailTruncation" baselineAdjustment="alignBaselines" adjustsFontSizeToFit="NO" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="KrQ-5T-fSH">
                                        <rect key="frame" x="8" y="8" width="112" height="21"/>
                                        <color key="backgroundColor" red="0.99953407049999998" green="0.98835557699999999" blue="0.47265523669999998" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="sRGB"/>
                                        <fontDescription key="fontDescription" type="system" pointSize="17"/>
                                        <nil key="textColor"/>
                                        <nil key="highlightedColor"/>
                                    </label>
                                </subviews>
                                <color key="backgroundColor" red="0.46202266219999999" green="0.83828371759999998" blue="1" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="sRGB"/>
                                <constraints>
                                    <constraint firstItem="j0p-3A-LQb" firstAttribute="bottom" secondItem="6dS-VR-QcN" secondAttribute="bottom" constant="8" id="1yq-cx-1GE"/>
                                    <constraint firstItem="6dS-VR-QcN" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="KrQ-5T-fSH" secondAttribute="bottom" constant="1200" id="BpQ-El-04G"/>
                                    <constraint firstItem="KrQ-5T-fSH" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="j0p-3A-LQb" secondAttribute="top" constant="8" id="JhA-o5-VKG"/>
                                    <constraint firstItem="KrQ-5T-fSH" firstAttribute="leading" secondItem="j0p-3A-LQb" secondAttribute="leading" constant="8" id="axd-l2-1aY"/>
                                    <constraint firstItem="6dS-VR-QcN" firstAttribute="trailing" secondItem="j0p-3A-LQb" secondAttribute="trailing" constant="8" id="han-0E-Nx6"/>
                                    <constraint firstItem="6dS-VR-QcN" firstAttribute="leading" secondItem="KrQ-5T-fSH" secondAttribute="trailing" constant="11" id="vB2-hP-NmI"/>
                                </constraints>
                                <viewLayoutGuide key="contentLayoutGuide" id="j0p-3A-LQb"/>
                                <viewLayoutGuide key="frameLayoutGuide" id="wx7-6c-6AG"/>
                            </scrollView>
                        </subviews>
                        <viewLayoutGuide key="safeArea" id="5O3-dC-9nE"/>
                        <color key="backgroundColor" systemColor="systemBackgroundColor"/>
                        <constraints>
                            <constraint firstItem="2QQ-od-V3W" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="5O3-dC-9nE" secondAttribute="top" constant="20" id="1P9-kk-0OW"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="2QQ-od-V3W" firstAttribute="leading" secondItem="5O3-dC-9nE" secondAttribute="leading" constant="20" id="Isk-wd-i1O"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="5O3-dC-9nE" firstAttribute="bottom" secondItem="2QQ-od-V3W" secondAttribute="bottom" constant="20" id="dhp-c0-XAb"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="5O3-dC-9nE" firstAttribute="trailing" secondItem="2QQ-od-V3W" secondAttribute="trailing" constant="20" id="eYJ-in-3Lv"/>
                        </constraints>
                    </view>
                </viewController>
                <placeholder placeholderIdentifier="IBFirstResponder" id="iqc-7R-rKj" userLabel="First Responder" customClass="UIResponder" sceneMemberID="firstResponder"/>
            </objects>
            <point key="canvasLocation" x="-416.25" y="128.75"/>
        </scene>
    </scenes>
    <resources>
        <systemColor name="systemBackgroundColor">
            <color white="1" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="genericGamma22GrayColorSpace"/>
        </systemColor>
    </resources>
</document>
```

Comment: Thanks mate . Really appreciate